# Rails dropped all of my tables unexpectedly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, osx-mountain-lion, rails-postgresql

As far as I can tell, Rails just dropped and rebuilt all the tables in my development environment.  I know what you're thinking, and I may be a klutz, but not *that* much of a klutz.

I was minding my own business, typing some Rails-esque queries in the console when suddenly I started getting null responses.  A quick check showed all my models had a count of zero.

Here's what log/development.log shows.  The first line is normal.  Everything after that is suspect:

```
Utilities::WebCache Load (1.6ms) SELECT "web_caches".* FROM "web_caches" WHERE "web_caches"."key" = '9650829252_05475407_2013-10-01 ORDER BY "web_caches"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
(203.8ms) DROP TABLE "analyses"
(169.6ms) CREATE TABLE "analyses" ("id" serial primary key, "service_account_id" integer, "type" character varying(255), "start_time" timestamp, "end_time" timestamp, "value" float) 
 (37.7ms) CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "idx_analyses_on_params" ON "analyses" USING btree ("service_account_id", "type", "start_time", "end_time")
 (82.6ms) DROP TABLE "proxy_homes"
 (88.1ms) CREATE TABLE "proxy_homes" ("id" serial primary key, "home_id" integer, "owner_name" character varying(255), "owner_email" character varying(255))
 (44.2ms) DROP TABLE "service_accounts"
 (19.2ms) CREATE TABLE "service_accounts" ("id" serial primary key, "proxy_home_id" integer, "type" character varying(255))
...
```

To me, it appears that something triggered a rebuild of all the tables.  The only culprit I can imagine is the test suite, which *was* running (via autotest) in a separate task.

Has anyone seen this happen before?  (I'd be more panicked, but luckily I have a `db/seeds.rb` file that rebuilds everything I need for my development work.)

Comment: you must have done something to cause it. Rails won't spontaneously drop and recreate your tables.

Comment: database_cleaner running in development?

Comment: Nope, not using db cleaner.  But if the test suite (running via autotest) momentarily found itself in the development environment, that could explain it.  Perhaps a thread safety issue?